# Golang Json Marshal Byte Array

Tags: json, go, type-conversion

is there a way to preserve the string representation of a byte array when
the surrounding struct is marshalled using the Golang JSON library?
The problem does not occur with integer types.

Example:

```
type foo struct {
    Array   []byte
    Name    string
}

func main() {
    tmp := foo{Array: []byte{1, 2, 3}, Name: "EPFL"}
    mar, _ := json.Marshal(tmp)
    fmt.Println(string(mar))
}
```

Should output

```
{"Array":[1,2,3],"Name":"EPFL"}
```

Instead of

```
{"Array":"AQID","Name":"EPFL"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have no control over the input. It's a struct containing a byte array. The above is just an illustration.

Comment: True that. Thank you.

Comment: was marked a duplicate but is not the same question, however similar

Comment: And why is it not the same? Because here `[]byte` is used, and `[]uint8` in the other question? `byte` is alias for `uint8`.

Comment: the use cases of the questions are different, but I guess if @quantik believes it answers his question it's a duplicate

Comment: They're very similar. According to the docs bytes are always converted during marshalling. Thus I should settle with an intermediate struct to avoid the problem.

Comment: You can also define a new type which implements the Marshaler interface, 

    type fooBytes []byte

    func (fb fooBytes) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
        b := []int{}
        for n := 0; n < len(fb); n++ {
            b = append(b, int(fb[n]))
        }
        return json.Marshal(b)
}

Comment: if the issue wasn't closed, I could show the full example :)

Comment: @baloo But a full example of your proposal is in the answer to the marked duplicate question.

Comment: @icza how does that comment add any value?